# how to get if volley finished working?

Tags: android, android-volley

Here's my code, I want to fill List from db and then use it of course,but I've got problem, it's doing asychronouz and when I'm trying to get value from this list, I'm getting out of bound exception, how should I restyle this method or how should I call from Mainactivity to solve this problem?

```
public class VolleySingleton extends Application {
public static final String TAG = VolleySingleton.class.getSimpleName();
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private static VolleySingleton instance;
public static int count=0;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance = this;
}

public static synchronized VolleySingleton getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (requestQueue == null) {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }
    return requestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
    count++;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> request) {
    getRequestQueue().add(request);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (requestQueue != null) {
        requestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
```

}

```
private static String TAG = JSonParse.class.getSimpleName();

public static List<Room> getRoomArray(String url, Context context) throws InterruptedException {
    final List<Room> roomList = new ArrayList<>();
    final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            try {
                Room room = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    room = new Room();
                    JSONObject newRoom = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                    room.setId(newRoom.getLong("id"));
                    room.setName(newRoom.getString("name"));
                    room.setActive(newRoom.getBoolean("active"));
                    roomList.add(room);
                }
                Helper.initList(roomList);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            volleyError.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    VolleySingleton.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(arrayRequest);
    return roomList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can process data in

`public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
//process response
}`

In onResponse Volley completed its work.
You can set callbacks here to send response in your class.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: 1. create a interface 

" public interface OnResponseReceived {
 public void responseReceived(JSONArray response);
 }"

2.Implement this interface in your activity

3.While calling Volley method "getRoomArray()" pass instance of your activity

4.Now you can call method "responseReceived(jsonArray)" in Volley response and pass array to that methos.So you will get that array in your Activity

Comment: I've not downvoted, actually it's not absolutely clear what to do in implementation of this interface :/

Comment: implement this interface in your Activity and override its methos in Activity "public class A extends Activity implements OnResponseReceived  {
public void responseReceived(JSONArray jsonArray) {
//parse json here and add to DB
}
}"

Comment: okay I've done it But getting same error, it's doing still asynchronously and when I'm trying to get one of the element of list getting outofboundexception

Comment: then may be issue is with your database write and read operations.May be read operation getting performed before completion of write.

Comment: what you mean in write operation?